# is there a common way of denoting the last element of an ordered set?

Tags: notation, order-theory

Ordered sets may (or may not) have last elements. Is there a common way of denoting the last element of an ordered set. For example if we define $A$ to be the ordered set $\langle \mathbb N, >\rangle$ (the naturals in reverse order), $A$ has a last element $0$. (...,3,2,1,0).

Would it make sense to denote $A$'s last element $a_{\omega^{\downarrow}}$ ($\omega^{\downarrow}$ being the order type of $A$) or maybe $a_{|A|}$?

or something better?

Comment: What about "$max(A)$" ?

Comment: Max isn’t bad. For example if your set is the reals from 1 to 2 inclusive.

Comment: I'm afraid max could be confusing when we have reverse orders (as shown in the example) and all kinds of "pathological" orders that don't imply the size of a number or of an object

Comment: The last element of a linear order is its maximum. So using $\max$ is not only correct, it is also appropriate.

Comment: Also, reverse orders are usually denoted by $*$, so $\omega^*$. The down arrow usually denotes the cone below a point.

Comment: I rather enjoy torturing my readers by writing such sequences using nonpositive indexes: $(...,a_{-3},a_{-2},a_{-1},a_0)$.

Comment: what about $a_{\top}$?